# connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I need help to connect my express app and MongoDB.
I believe I wrote code perfectly, but I haven't been known how to connect to MongoDB. Oh, I am new to MongoDB and Atlas.
As I googled, I need to add an IP address in which I wanna use db on Atlas. I did so like below.
[image: MongoDB Atlas]
I don't know why /32 was added at the end of 127.0.0.1. I tried to add "localhost", but got an error. I found so many solutions on googled such as writing 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost. I tried everything but it still doesn't work. Please help me with the error. Thanks so much in advance.

Here are my code. I don't think there is an issue.

```js
const express = require("express")
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const articleRouter = require('./routes/articles')
const app = express()

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/blog')
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/blog', {
  useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true
})

// 2
// mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/blog',
//   err => {
//     if(err) throw err;
//     console.log('connected to MongoDB')
// })

// 3
// mongoose.connect('mongodb://0.0.0.0:27017/',
//   err => {
//     if(err) throw err;
//     console.log('connected to MongoDB')
// })

// 4
// var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
// MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/MyDb", function (err, db) {
//   if(err) throw err;
// });

// 5
// const mongoose = require("mongoose");
// mongoose.connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/blog")
// .then(() => {
//   console.log("Connected to Database");
// })
// .catch((err) => {
//   console.log("Not Connected to Database ERROR! ", err);
// });

app.set('view engine', 'ejs')

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  const articles = [{
    title: "Test Article",
    createdAt: new Date(),
    description: "test description"
  }, {
    title: "Test Article2",
    createdAt: new Date(),
    description: "test description"
  }]

  res.render('articles/index', { articles: articles })
})

app.use('/articles', articleRouter)
app.listen(5000)
```

```js
const express = require('express')
const Article = require('./../models/article')
const router = express.Router()

router.get('/new', (req, res) => {
  res.render('articles/new', { article: new Article() })
})
router.get('/:id', async (req, res) => {
  const article = await Article.findById(req.params.id)
  if (article === null) res.redirect('/')
  res.render('articles/show', { article: article })
})

router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
  let article = new Article({
    title: req.body.title,
    description: req.body.description,
    markdown: req.body.markdown,
  })
  try {
    article = await article.save()
    res.redirect(`/articles/${article.id}`)
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
    res.render('articles/new', { article: article })
  }
})


module.exports = router
```

Comment: have you configured mongodb on the local host to listen to port 27017 - is mongodb running? does it have permission to listen on 127.0.0.1:27017? Ahh. I see from the comment below that mongo would NOT be running on the local host

Comment: You are thinking of this in the wrong way. The error is not saying that IP address "127.0.0.1:27017" is restricted/blocked. Your mongoose configuration is trying to connect to mongodb running locally at localhost, not in cloud atlas. You would need to update your configuration to point to Atlas (go to database in Atlas and connect to get values).

Comment: You are trying to connect to a local MongoDB server when your MongoDB server is on the cloud. Sounds reasonable? :)

Comment: This is not the address to reach your mongoDB instance:
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/blog')

The actual address should look like an URL, you can get it from the databases tab

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys. I looked up the MongoDB website and noticed that there were some kinds of use of MongoDB.

Comment: Hey guys!! When I replace the url from 'mongodb://localhost/blog' to "mongodb+srv://masa:<password>@cluster0.8tjjn.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority", it worked!!! Thank you all so much^^

Comment: Very many people (esp. beginners) think that `127.0.0.1` is your localhost address. However in fact it is the range `127.0.0.1` to `127.255.255.254`. So, for example `ping 127.100.100.100` pings your local machine!